# How to exclude/hide specific directories/folders from search in Atom Editor, per project

Tags: ide, atom-editor

I have a directory with a bunch of Bootstrap versions in it, and every time I search my project for a Boostrap-related classname, I get a list with all the hits from my Bootstrap versions. I need to know how to exclude this directory from searches. I do not want to do this globally, and I'm not looking to use the search/pattern field in the 'find' panel (unless this field can get populated from a config file in the project). I need a solution that will persist every time I open this specific project in the future. Would this configuration be in `.editorconfig` or `config.cson`?

I searched for this solution elsewhere, but there's a lot of noise in the threads related to my question, so it's hard to identify the correct/best solution.

[Edit]: To be clear, I'm not looking to rely on `.gitignore`, since that will result in files omitted from version control. And I'm not looking to set a preference for fuzzy-finder, since this will be global, and could exclude items in other projects.

[Edit]: This, so far, sounds like a missing feature.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of the *Exclude VCS Ignored Paths* feature. If you check the box on this entry in Atom's *Settings* screen, and then add the folder that you want to exclude from the search to your VCS's ignore file (e.g. `.gitignore` for a Git repo), then entries in that ignored directory will no longer show up in your search results.

So if your folder is called `bootstrap-versions`, and your project is a Git repo, then adding

```
bootstrap-versions
```

to your project's `.gitignore` file will remove this folder from the search results.

---

As an alternative to that, you can add the name of the folder to be ignored in the `fuzzy-finder` *Ignored Names* field. Go to *Settings > Packages* and type *fuzzy* in the search box. Then select the *Settings* button of the `fuzzy-finder` package and enter the name of your folder to the *Ignored Names* field.

The *Core Settings* page has the same field, you could add the folder there as well.

Just be aware that these are global and will impact all projects.

Comment: Ok, so the first solution will result in my directory being excluded from Git, which I don't want. And the second setting looks like it's global, so will ignore this directory in all my projects, which I also don't want.

Comment: Yes, these are unfortunately the side effects... I don't have any other suggestions at this point, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this with Atom.  YMMV:

https://github.com/atom/find-and-replace/issues/149#issuecomment-142323938

Preferences -> Open Config Folder -> config.cson):

```
"*":
  core:
    autoHideMenuBar: true
    ignoredNames: [
      ".meteor"
      ".git"
      "etc"
    ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Find -> Find in Project

Example: input `-dirName/subDir` in "File/directory pattern" to exclude searching the directory